# iOS autolayout locating images at the same line with same ration for each views

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, autolayout, swift4

I am working on studying iOS autolayout

However, which constraints and functions should I use for making those views have the same location.

I mean, I want to locate those two `UIImageView` at center like the first picture. But, whenever I change the `UIView`, they go down and down... what should I do?

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    let firstView:UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "angry").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()
    let secondView:UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "crying").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         return imageView
    }()

    let thirdView:UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "heartEmpty").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()

    let fourthView:UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "joy").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()


    func setupViews() {

        view.addSubview(firstView)

       // setup first view
        firstView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        firstView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        firstView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        firstView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true

        view.addSubview(secondView)

    // setup second view
        secondView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstView.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        secondView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        secondView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
       secondView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    view.addSubview(thirdView)

       thirdView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondView.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
       thirdView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
       thirdView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
       thirdView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
       view.addSubview(fourthView)

       fourthView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdView.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
      fourthView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
       fourthView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
       fourthView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
```

}

}

Comment: give me your storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Hello My Friend You Can Make It By Code Or By Storyboard using stack view  i will show you by code below hope this help you

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let firstView:UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()

        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "MyImage").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()

    let secondView:UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()

    }

    func setupViews() {

        view.addSubview(firstView)

        // setup first view
        firstView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        firstView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        firstView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        firstView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true

        view.addSubview(secondView)

        // setup second view
        secondView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstView.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        secondView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        secondView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        secondView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi I did like that but, How can I make this code to be shown in the storyboard or the testing app.?

Comment: actually it works, but it has not resized for both Iphone5 and iPhone7.

Comment: It’s work for all ,have you picture for the issue in iPhone 5 and 7?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these Steps, you can do it in Storyboard.

1 - Select first Image, align it horizontally and vertically in container by giving it constraints using the "align" tab which is usually located at the bottom-right corner of the storyboard window.

2 - Now, select the first image and goto Size Inspector.Scroll down to it's constraints and there will be a constraint named as "Align Center X To : SuperView".

3 - There will be an "Edit" label right beside it.Click on it, and a popover will show up.

4 - in the popover , in the first Line it will show Constant = 0.

5 - Now here's the fun part, if you put negative value in it , say "-20" it will move 20 spaces to the left.Similarly, if you put "20", it will move 20 spaces to the right.

Now, do the same for the second image until you have achieved your result. Both the images will now be in the centre of the screen.

I am new to IOS as Well, but this worked for me and I hope it works for u as well. :-)